# How to determine num entries per minute in pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a breakdown of how many times an entry in the 'f' column is listed per minute.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt

    f= ['f0001',
        'f0001',
        'f0001',
        'f0001',
        'f0020',
        'f0008',
        'f0001',
        'f0005',
        'f3203',
        'f0002',
        'f0002',
        'f0001',
        'f0201',
        'f0001',
        'f0439',
        'f0233',
        'f0008',
        'f0003',
        'f0009',
        'f0005']


    dates = ['20130101100103', '20130101100110',
               '20130101100125', '20130101100133',
               '20130101100100', '20130101100200',
               '20130101100200', '20130101100200',
               '20130101100200', '20130101100200',
               '20130101100200', '20130101100300',
               '20130101100300', '20130101100300',
               '20130101100300', '20130101100400',
               '20130101100400', '20130101100400',
               '20130101100400', '20130101100400']


    d = {'date':  dates}
    data = pd.DataFrame(d)
    data['user'] = f

    data.date = data.date.apply(str)
    data.date = data.date.apply(lambda x: 
    dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))

    s = data.groupby([data.date.map(lambda t: t.minute)]).count()
```

But so far all I've got is the below

```
s

    date    user
date        
1   5   5
2   6   6
3   4   4
4   5   5
```

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there. You just need to add `data['user']` into your groupby clause as well.

```
data.groupby([[data.date.dt.minute, data['user']]).count().rename(columns={'date':'count'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
date    user    count
0   1   f0001   4
1   1   f0020   1
2   2   f0001   1
3   2   f0002   2
4   2   f0005   1
5   2   f0008   1
6   2   f3203   1
7   3   f0001   2
8   3   f0201   1
9   3   f0439   1
10  4   f0003   1
11  4   f0005   1
12  4   f0008   1
13  4   f0009   1
14  4   f0233   1
```

Comment: `data.date.dt.minute` instead of `map`

Comment: I had to change columns={'date':'count'} bc I wanted to do s[s.count >5] and that gave an error so I used columns={'date':'num'} so s[s.num >5] worked just fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='min'))['user'].value_counts()
```

**Full example**, including how to create your dataframe in a much easier way, using `pandas` functions (I know that this wasn't the topic of your question, but I think the following makes it much easier rather than importing `datetime`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'user':f})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='min'))['user'].value_counts()
```

The result:

```
date                 user 
2013-01-01 10:01:00  f0001    4
                     f0020    1
2013-01-01 10:02:00  f0002    2
                     f0001    1
                     f0005    1
                     f0008    1
                     f3203    1
2013-01-01 10:03:00  f0001    2
                     f0201    1
                     f0439    1
2013-01-01 10:04:00  f0003    1
                     f0005    1
                     f0008    1
                     f0009    1
                     f0233    1
Name: user, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Seems like OP only needs minutes in number and not the entire date.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not really sure though, OP didn't specify. My answer, I believe, does address "*how many times an entry in the 'f' column is listed per minute*". In any case, your answer works too (+1 :) )

Comment: OP did have expected output before. not sure why he edited the question. You are right. Your answer does answer OP's question. +1

Comment: full date is fine. the rate ( user/min ) was the pertinent issue.

Comment: I edited the content b/c *someone* couldn't enter the question into the correct SO format ( kept getting formatting errors ) .